# Key binding to wrap a selection with an html tag in VSCode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

Is there a default key binding in VSCode to wrap a selection in an HTML tag like the keyboard shortcut Shift+alt+W in Visual studio 2015?  I could not find anything similar in documentation or in the default keyboard shortcuts  that indicates its availability out of the box.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To automate this go to.

File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

and add this into your keybindings.json (right hand side window)

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+enter",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

You can replace ctrl+shift+enter with your own key combination.

Comment: That's true! You can also use the command palette (ctrl+shift+p) and write "emmet wrap" and then autocompletion will show you the command. I am using the command palette quite a lot lately when I don't want to bind any key to a command

Comment: Is it possible to specify the tag in the keybinding? e.g., <code>...</code>?

Answer (score 6):

you can use this extension:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-htmltagwrap

or you can:

1. open the Command Palette: Command/Control+Shift+P (⇧⌘P)
2. type "wrap", then select "Wrap with abbreviation"
3. type the tag you want and press enter

Comment: This extension allows redefining the default tag (saves some key strokes for me), e.g., for `<code>...</code>`  use `"htmltagwrap.tag": "code"`

Comment: As of 2021/1/25, the vscode-htmltagwrap extension was last updated in 2016. I think you'll have better luck with [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) which is built in to VS Code. See [this sibling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42434314/109618).

Answer (score 1):

Or simply search for the HTMLtagwrap extension in VScode, Make selection. Then use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. Then enter the new tag.

Comment: As of 2021/1/25, the vscode-htmltagwrap extension was last updated in 2016. I think you'll have better luck with [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) which is built in to VS Code. See [this sibling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42434314/109618).