# Prevent autoClosingTags when desired or define closing tag location?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The autoClosingTags feature of vsCode is quite convenient, when you are creating a clompletely new element without having its content already in the code. However for the letter, its quite annoying since it places the closing tag right after the opening tag. Then you have to select the closing tag, cut it and place it where you actually want it to be.

Is there a way to either not have a closing tag created in some situations or to wrap the tags over a certain content in the first place?
Or any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Wrap them? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155875/how-to-do-tag-wrapping-in-vs-code/46854557#46854557

Comment: Yes, in the sense of putting a opening tag at the start of a desired content and at the end of it to make the created element embrace that content.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421335/key-binding-to-wrap-a-selection-with-an-html-tag-in-vscode